# Datagridview Cell Validating with formatted databaound object

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I have a a very simple datagridview representing a order items list. I have one column that represents a discount value with this definition:

```
column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.DataPropertyName = "Discount";
column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0\\%";
column.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
column.Width = 80;
column.Name = "Discount";
dgvOrderDetails.Columns.Add(column);
```

The column discount gets formated as "5%" if the Discount (INT) property has a value of 5, but when I try to edit the value with the CellValidating it fails because it tries to validate the formatted value "5% inset of the int value '5', if I try to validate with the Cell.Value I get the old value, not the new one.

```
private void dgvOrderDetails_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
        switch(e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case LINE_DISCOUNT:
                {
                    decimal discount = 0;

                    // Valido que la cantidad haya sido ingresada correctamente
                    if (!Decimal.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out discount)
                        || discount < 0 || discount > 100)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        dgvOrderDetails.EndEdit();
                        MessageBox.Show("El porcentaje debe ser un número entero mayor o igual a 0 y menor o igual a 100");
                    }

                    if (OnDiscountModified != null)
                        OnDiscountModified(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
                break;
        }
}
```